# Autocomplete in joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, autocomplete

I'd like to add the autocomplete to a joomla componenet that I'm developing
I used JQuery 
I follwed this exemple

http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/

The exemple work well but there is some problem

1 - When you add JQuery with joomla you have some problems with mootlools
wen I added Jquery with this code

```
 if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery'))
        {
             JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
             $document = JFactory::getDocument();
             $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "administrator/components/com_tkcontrack/assets/js/jquery.js");
        }
        if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery.min'))
        {
             JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery.min',true);
             $document = JFactory::getDocument();
             $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "administrator/components/com_tkcontrack/assets/js/jquery.min.js");
        }
        if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery-ui.min'))
        {
             JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery-ui.min',true);
             $document = JFactory::getDocument();
             $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "administrator/components/com_tkcontrack/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js");

        }
```

I got some Javascript error with Mootools(thank's to firebug)

2 - Even I think some css does not work any more

Well can someone please help me to add autcomplete to joomla componene, and how to add JQuery to Joomla without having problem

Actually I tried to add JQuery with onther way, edit this file 
\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer

but I does not work I have problem with Jquery then

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: 1.5 - well I have to work with it for work purpose -

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on what the error is exactly but it sounds like a conflict.

First of all, you're using the correct method to ensure your scripts only get imported once, however check Firebug see see if you only have 1 of each being imported just in case. You will then need to call noConflict like so:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration( $noconflict );
```

What you could also do to import jQuery and jQuery UI only once and in noConflict mode is use the [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) Plugin:

One of the features that will apply to you is:

- places jQuery libraries after MooTools calls for perfect compatibility

Hope this helps

Comment: Well I did not understand what the $nonconflict in the $document->addScriptDeclaration( $noconflict ); is ? well the problem that firebug show is TypeError: document.getElementsBySelector is not a function in the mootools.js file , When I reomve JQuery declaration nothing is wrong

Comment: view.html.php in the view folder before   parent::display($tpl)(the last line )

Comment: hmm well as mentioned in my answer, try using the jQuery Easy plugin which will solves everything for you

Answer (score 0):

replace above code with

```
 JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

and in your js file start like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // your code goes here
}
```

to get ready-made code you can use [JQUERY UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in `ready` function

Comment: Well is this JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); import alos the JQUERY UI ?and all other script that I included in the top of the question?

Comment: JHtml::_('jquery.ui'); this willl enable jquery ui. This is a useful link to know more about how and what these JHTML statements are doing. http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Javascript_Frameworks. You need not to include above libraries just useJHTML to do all that stuff

Comment: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework')` is the recommended way ant it's available since Joomla 3.0